# PHP: Log into an "global array"

Tags: php, logging, error-handling, global-variables

I've got a question.

I'm running a little PHP-CLI-Script which calls functions from a helper-class.

Like this:

test.php

```
$TestHelper         =           new TestHelper();    
$test = $TestHelper->method1();
if($test) $TestHelper->method2();
```

helper.php

```
class TestHelper
{
public static function method1()
{
...
addlogfunction("This is a test-log-entry");
}
public static function method2()
{
...
addlogfunction("This is another test-log-entry");
}
...
}
```

Both methods are defined in helper.php.

Now I would like to write some information, which are generated by running both methods, to a "global log". This log should contain information about both called methods.

In this case the "global log" should contain "This is a test-log-entry" AND "This is another test-log-entry" after running both methods successively.

How could I solve that?

Comment: 1. Your methods doesn't return anything 2. [`error_log()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) ?!

Comment: Oh, the methods return something  - method 1 returns either an array of results or false. But "false" can be caused by many different things.

Answer (score 0):

Add the log messages to an array, and hope there is a way to output it later. Because if the script crashes, the array will be lost, and the log won't be useful for debugging.

Command line scripts usually write to STDERR for errors, which will be usable to all other command line tools, can be written to log files etc.

[error_log()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php1) would do it if configured correctly (the [error_log](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log) configuration directive).

You could also directly [write to STDERR](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php):

```
fwrite(STDERR, "Log messages to the error channel\n");
```

Comment: Hm, I would like to send the errors by mail. So I do not know if this is possible this way?

Comment: It depends on how you'd execute the script, but it should be easier and more flexible if you do the basic output to STDOUT and STDERR, and let the script caller decide if that output should go to a mail or anywhere else. Of course you can also collect every log in an array and send it via mail with PHP. Or you could add a logger that does all this (Log4PHP has appenders that can send mail - either individually per log event, or aggregated for the whole script call - other log libraries may do the same).